# Is there a measure for movie realism?

Tags: realism

I am a big fan of life-close movies where things are portrayed close to what could have happened in real life. Such movies usually attempt preserving realism and follow high level of detail.

Is there a special measure of how well realism is portrayed in a movie? Or is it something that no one really cares about?

The reason for this question is actually to add an extra criterion in my search for the next movie I wish to watch.

Answer (score 5):

*Truth* is something that can't be measured, it has to be reviewed manually according to certain criteria. So there is no automatic method to determine the realism of a movie, people need to put a lot of work into it. You can find such information about mistakes e.g. in some movie reviews or in the [goofs section of IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112573/goofs) (namely *Anachronisms*, *Character errors*, *Factual errors*, *Errors in geography*). This so-called free Encyclopaedia also typically has details about [popular culture and its mistakes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braveheart#Historical_inaccuracy).

David McCandless did a scene-by-scene review of the truth of a few movies. He used *Unknown*, *False*, *False-Ish*, *True-Ish*, and *True* as categories for each scene. You can find the result [here](http://www.informationisbeautiful.net/visualizations/based-on-a-true-true-story/) and the raw data [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sJDpzYH_sMYuYHqkmZeJGIq_TEXGDjboYdSoew7UjZ8/edit#gid=1961296402).

So, yes, other people do care. Still, movies are economical entertainment products and not documentaries. Determining the realism is a lot of work that in detail is not justified normally. Find a few good movie reviewers / bloggers whose style you like and who put a general emphasis on this. Reading about inaccuracies in detail before watching a movie will, of course, lead to a lot of spoilers.

Answer (score 3):

Regrettably, movies must be entertaining enough to bring people in to theaters. Sometimes characters must be nicer than they really were; be combined to a more interesting, larger force than real life permitted; do things they wouldn't do to generate **conflict**. Without conflict there is no drama.

If there was less in life than a compelling film requires (in someone's judgement), then some gets added. To create conflict where there was none, or wouldn't reasonably be any if just fiction with 'realistic' characters, then characters **must** behave badly or irrationally. Then there's opposition, confrontation, conflict. Frequently this interferes with factual reporting.